# How to deal with interview situation where computer screen is shown only a short time?

Tags: interviewing

Could anyone explain what the employer wanted me to react in this situation?

I was in a job interview for a developer job. Boss wanted to see how well I understand code. He showed the code for about 15 seconds and then the screen went black or computer shut down or there were some issue with projector. I just waited that he fixes the problem but nothing happened.

Is the idea just say what I remember on the code or fix the issue why I won't see the code or say that I need more time figure out where the problem is or something else, like how do one reacts in uncommon situations?

I did not got the job.

Comment: Only your boss knows what they expected you to do.  As a random person on the internet, I could speculate or guess, but that won't be helpful in this situation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only the person who conducted the interview could possibly answer.

Comment: I think the fact that the hiring manager did nothing or didn't react when this happen might indicate that he wanted to see how you would react. But as Mike mentioned, it's very hard to speculate. Did you have any initiative in wanting to be able to look at the code again? If I was you I would have said, "Do you all need any help? Is there any other way, I can see the code again?" From what you've told us, it just sounds like you were not interested in seeing the code again and just waited for something to happen.

Comment: If in doubt, ask questions. Whats gone wrong? What am I meant to do? You should really buy more reliable equipment? What are you asking? What do you mean? Why would I want to work at a company that has constant equipment failure? Anything is better than sitting silently on a problem and waiting for it to solve itself.

Comment: This waves a large, red flag at me. I would not want to work for this person.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hate these kind of ad-hoc weird interview tests as much as anyone - it's putting you on the spot in an unrealistic situation that's unlikely to occur in your daily work, and it's beyond unrealistic to expect you'd react exactly the same way in an interview and if you were a full time employee.

That being said:

> I just waited that he fixes the problem but nothing happened.

I think it's fair to say not doing anything was almost certainly the *wrong* thing to do. They were likely expecting some reaction - that could even be as simple as flagging up the issue. I likely would have simply said

> There's clearly an issue here - can we get the code back on the screen so I can take a proper look?

That may or may not have been the "correct" reaction, and from that they may have then just put it back up, or said no, or asked you to design a kitchen for 3 legged llamas instead - but it's important to continually engage rather than just freeze up.

Comment: yup, the real question is "how to professionally handle situation" and the only way is to engage

Comment: The only way? Another, equally professional, way is to say "I don't think that we are going to be a good match. Thank you for your time. I can find my own way out".

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I'd be a bit careful of that in this instance in case it was a *genuine* unplanned issue. In retrospect we may know that's not the case, but I'd generally save that reaction for the most extreme circumstances.

Comment: A great point!! Upvote -  I had not thought of that. However, if it ***is*** a "gotcha test", then I do not wish to work there

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I quite agree. Some people seem to forget *employers* can fail an interview as well as candidates. That kind of stunt would almost certainly be a fail in my book.

Comment: How was it the wrong thing to do? Was he supposed to put his old Geek Squad shirt on and start diagnosing the technical issues? How does that speak to his skills as a developer? Its not like he was applying for technical support here. This answer is nonsense.

Comment: @TheBatman Err, what?! My example response was simply asking for the code back on the screen so the OP could continue looking at it. I'm genuinely baffled as to how you've gleaned "start diagnosing the technical issues" from the above.